# Org mode timestamp format when exported

Tags: datetime, emacs, org-mode

I'm exporting my org-mode file to LaTeX, and often use the `C-c .` timestamp as a top level heading as sort of a rolling diary.

However, when it exports to PDF, `<2014-04-25 Fri>` looks a little funny.  Is there a general setting that would convert the timestamps to some kind of formatted date, like "Friday, April 25, 2014" or some other kind of common datestring format?

I looked [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html#Timestamps) and understand that there are a couple ways of entering dates, but I imagine there must be output formatting, too.  I see also that there is an export timestamp setting [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html),

```
<:
Toggle inclusion of any time/date active/inactive stamps (org-export-with-timestamps).
```

But am unclear on what implementation would mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
(let ((org-time-stamp-custom-formats
       '("<%A, %B %d, %Y>" . "<%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M>"))
      (org-display-custom-times 't))
  (org-latex-export-to-latex))
```

Upd.: If you want to remove brackets `<>` from output string, you have to patch the function `org-translate-time`. Normal behaviour:

```
(let ((org-time-stamp-custom-formats
       '("<%A, %B %d, %Y>" . "<%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M>"))
      (org-display-custom-times 't))
  (org-translate-time "<2014-04-29 Tu.>")) => "<Tuesday, April 29, 2014>"
```

With patched function like here https://gist.github.com/boykov/11387660

```
(let ((org-time-stamp-custom-formats
       '("<%A, %B %d, %Y>" . "<%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M>"))
      (org-display-custom-times 't))
  (org-translate-time "<2014-04-29 Tu.>")) => "Tuesday, April 29, 2014"
```

The brackets `<>` are hardcoded in the function `org-translate-time` and you can't remove their by fixing `org-time-stamp-custom-formats` only.

Comment: So, I'd change line 2 to `'("<%Y-%m-%d %a>" . "%A, %B %d, %Y"))` in my case?  I didn't seem to get any results either from using the version you list or that one, I'm afraid.

Comment: No, the first item in the list is for date without hours and minutes and the second is for date with H:M. I updated my answer, there is no simple way to remove brackets `<>` from the date.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of patching `org-translate-time`, you can remove brackets by adding the following function to `org-export-filter-timestamp-functions`:

```
(defun org-export-filter-timestamp-remove-brackets (timestamp backend info)
  "removes relevant brackets from a timestamp"
  (cond
   ((org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "[<>]\\|[][]" "" timestamp))
   ((org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "&[lg]t;\\|[][]" "" timestamp))))

(eval-after-load 'ox '(add-to-list
                       'org-export-filter-timestamp-functions
                       'org-export-filter-timestamp-remove-brackets))
```

See http://endlessparentheses.com/better-time-stamps-in-org-export.html for more details.

Comment: Seems that this sadly wouldn't help if you want to control timestamps in the headings (e.g. next to TODO states), so in such case patching `org-timestamp-translate` is your best bet. Likely has something to do with this https://github.com/bzg/org-mode/blob/817c0c81e8f6d1dc387956c8c5b026ced62c157c/lisp/ox.el#L1896

Answer (score 2):

The following works well for me. I like it, because it does not require filtering out "[]" or "<>" and choosing the target format is very simple. Do not forget to allow `#+BIND` by setting `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` to `t`.

```
#+BIND: org-latex-inactive-timestamp-format "%s"
#+BIND: org-latex-active-timestamp-format "%s"
#+BIND: org-export-filter-timestamp-functions (tmp-f-timestamp)
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
  (defun tmp-f-timestamp (s backend info)
    (cond
     ((org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
      (let ((ts (org-timestamp-format (org-timestamp-from-string s) "%Y-%m-%d")))
        (format "\\fbox{\\textbf{%s}} " ts)
      ))
     (t s)))
#+END_SRC
```